# NSInteger problem

Tags: iphone, nsinteger

How to use the NSInteger give example and simplecode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSInteger` is defined like this:

```
#if __LP64__ || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
  typedef long NSInteger;
  typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
  typedef int NSInteger;
  typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

It's the same as `int` on 32Bit or `long` on 64Bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger a, b, c;

a = 2;
b = 40;

c = a + b;

NSLog(@"THE answer is: %d\n", c);
```